# .net HTML Encoding ISO10646 characters, Trade Mark, Euro, etc

Tags: .net, vb.net, html-encode

I am having a constant series of problems with encoding characters for output in an XML file through .NET.  I have a feeling that the problem relates to a setting on the Response object being used but I'm unable to get anywhere finding the correct setting.

If I do the following:

```
system.web.httpcontext.current.response.write("€ & ™" & server.HTMLEncode(" € & ™ "))
```

I get the following output:

```
€ & ™ € &amp; ™
```

The question is why are standard ASCII characters encoded, but the extended(?) characters not? Is there some kind of setting I need to give to the server object to tell it to convert characters like Euro/Trade Mark?

One of the bullet points of MSDN's HTMLEncode function page states that:

> Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80 is converted to &#, where  is the ASCII character value.

Comment: Are you looking at a recent version of the documentation? Are you sure this is not for classic ASP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking at the documentation for [classic ASP server objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

ASP.NET strings are Unicode based, not ASCII based and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) doesn't mention ASCII.

You could ensure ASCII encoding if you use the overload that takes a `TextWriter` initialized with an `Encoding.AsciiEncoding`.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I was looking at the wrong documentation, but I think the ASCII reference was a red herring.  I don't want to convert the string itself into Ascii.  If I use a text writer output will it not just convert any non-ascii characters to ? as though I'd used the Encoding.Convert method?

Apologies if this is what your explanation does cover as I may be misunderstanding, but I'm trying to get at why characters like Euro/Trademark are not encoded in any way by default whereas < or > are?

Comment: @JLo - They are not encoded because they are Unicode and browsers can view Unicode no problem. HTMLEncode uses UTF-8 by default, where these do not need to be encoded.

Comment: Thanks :) I'm glad I'm not going completely mad, this is all coming to light because of some external recipient of the data which claims we should be doing the encoding in the data we send.  As far as I'm concerned it's a recipient's responsibility to encode the data for the way they want to display it! But when your recipient is a large fruit-based computer firm you can't always win.  I think I can take it from here then!